# How to delete GoogleCloudFunctions older versions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Whenever i update, deploy & test cloud functions using command

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloHttp --trigger-http
```

At the end of the output, i can see versionId getting incremented, so i would like to know where i can find them if they are stored somewhere
, a new version gets created

```
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2018-07-08T05:56:24Z'
versionId: '6'
```

Eventually the way i update, deploy & test there might be hundreds. So, i would like to delete the older versions as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no option either via [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/delete) or the [API](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/delete) to delete a specific version of a Cloud Function. One option for you to avoid too many versions for a given Cloud Function is to separate tests and prod deployments. By default when a Google Cloud Function is triggered, it executes a JavaScript function with the same name, but you can override this behavior via the `--entry-point` flag.

For example, let's say you export a function named helloHttp, you can deploy your tests versions like this:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloHttpTest --trigger-http --entry-point helloHttp
```

Then once you're ready to deploy your function for production, you can deploy it as usual:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy helloHttp --trigger-http
```

You'll be able to delete your test function regularly.

Comment: any changes in this subject? i would like very much to stop keeing versions of my functions from 2 years ago